# Is the Baratza Virtuozo+ worth it compared to the Encore?

Tags: equipment, grinder

So I am kinda looking around for an upgraded coffee grinder. I am currently using a Braun KG7070. Super cheap, so not exceptionally good and doesn't really provide consistent grinds.

So I was looking around and the most obvious grinder seems to be the Baratza Encore. Used a lot and I heard good things about it. But I also saw that the Baratza Virtuozo+ provides even better grind quality. But it also costs about €100,- more. So I was wondering, is the Virtuozo+ worth it's money or should I go for the Encore?

I basically brew french press and pour-over currently. I know both aren't really well suited for espresso grinds, but I am not interested in that anyway so that isn't a problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can upgrade the Encore with the burrs from the Virtuozo if you are handy with some basic tools. So even if you started with the Encore and then down the road decided you wanted an upgrade, you could spend just €40 and get the same grind quality.

Comment: Cool, I did not know that! What is the difference between the burrs exactly?